# Add a quote item with a buy request

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I would like to get product price with options price using a custom module that calculates product price by formula, i like to use the function without adding the product to the cart.

The function get a quote item paramter

```
public function getProductFinalPrice($item, $forReindex = false, $storeId = null)
```

So i thought about add a quote item with a info_buyRequest buy request
I tried this

```
    $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(5862);
    $customOptions = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
    $item = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');

    $options = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\Collection');
    $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    $quote->addProduct($product);
    $quote->save();
    $options->setQuote($quote);
    //$options->addItemFilter($item->getId());
    $item->setQuote($quote)->setProduct($product)->setQty($qty);
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $item->addOption($option);
    }
    $infoBuyRequest = [
            "info_buyRequest" => [
                "uenc" => "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cud2V0YWcuY2EvZW5fY2EvbmFtZS10YWdzL25hbWUtdGFncy1pbnNwaXJhdGlvbi9jdXN0b20tbmFtZS10YWctb3JkZXIv",
                "product" => 5862,
                "qty" => $qty
            ]
        ];

    $option = $this->_objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Option::class,
        ['data' => $infoBuyRequest]
    );

    $item->addOption($option);
    $item->setProductOptions($infoBuyRequest);
    var_dump($this->_getBuyRequest($item));


  var_dump($this->_getBuyRequest($item)); return 
  object(Magento\Framework\DataObject)#3647 (1) {
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["original_qty"]=>
     NULL
    ["qty"]=>
     int(100)
  }
 }
```

I like to get something with info_buyrequest

```
            [
            "info_buyRequest" => [
                "uenc" => "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cud2V0YWcuY2EvZW5fY2EvbmFtZS10YWdzL25hbWUtdGFncy1pbnNwaXJhdGlvbi9jdXN0b20tbmFtZS10YWctb3JkZXIv",
                "product" => 5862,
                "qty" => $qty
            ]
        ]
```

This is the function _getBuyRequest

```
public function _getBuyRequest($item) { 
    $option = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
    if ($option) {
        $value = json_decode($option->getValue(), true); //in M2.2 json used for the buy request
        if (is_null($value))
            $value = unserialize($option->getValue()); //in M<2.2 the buy request is serialized
    } else
        $value = [];

    $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($value);

    // Overwrite standard buy request qty, because item qty could have changed since adding to quote
    $buyRequest->setOriginalQty($buyRequest->getQty())
            ->setQty($item->getQty() * 1);

    return $buyRequest;
}
```

So how to add info_buyRequest? i would like to load options in the quote item.

Comment: $options = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');

Comment: @MohitPatel i like to get product options without adding the product to cart, i edited my code